# Removing white space from UL in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

What's wrong with UL in the widget titled Suosituinta juuri nyt on https://poydalla.net/category/in-english/ ? On the front page, categories and blog posts it looks wrong, but on pages like https://poydalla.net/lautapelisuositukset/ it looks fine.

I tried comparing the CSS with the Inspect tool of Chrome, changing all the differences from the pages that were right to the ones that weren't right.

On top of that, I've googled a lot and tried different combos of margins, paddings, line-heights, displays (inline, block, flex etc.) When the other ones are fine, pages are screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what is *wrong* is your `margin-bottom: 40px;` for `.archive .post` selector. I guess this is intended to space the article teasers on archive pages but, as long as your `ul` items have also the class `post`, they're gonna be affected by this bottom margin.

It's difficult to give you a good solution without knowing your entire CSS (and the PHP giving the classes to your elements) but I guess your could try this possible solutions:

**If you are allowed to edit PHP/HTML**

Just remove the class `post` from your `li` items on the widget.

**If you only can edit CSS**

Adding `.archive li.post { margin-bottom: 0 }` to your CSS should be enough. Or you could modify this:

```
.blog .post,
.single .post,
.archive .post,
.search .post,
.search .page {
    margin-bottom: 40px
}
```

to this:

```
.blog article.post,
.single article.post,
.archive article.post,
.search article.post,
.search article.page {
    margin-bottom: 40px
}
```

Comment: Sadly the `.archive li.post { margin-bottom: 0 }` didn't work. 

The PHP gave classes using the following code 
`// wrap the items in li's.
    $classes = join( ' ', get_post_class() );
    
    $output .= '<li class="' . $classes . '">';`

Didn't know how to fix it so I added this:
`add_filter( 'post_class', 'remove_post_function', 20 );
function remove_posts_function( $classes ) {
 if( ( $key = array_search( 'post', $classes ) ) !== false )
  unset( $classes[$key] );
 return $classes;
}`
(Copied from [https://php.quicoto.com/how-to-remove-a-class-from-post_class-wordpress/]